Wifi hotspot and bluetooth headset don't work together. Hotpost stops sharing internet
I am using Debian 12.7. If I turn on hotspot and connect my Bluetooth headset, hotspot stops sharing internet. On Windows it worked fine.
Run: lspci -vnn | grep Network
Show: 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
